# How do I install GCC 4.7.2 on OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, gcc

How do I install GCC 4.7.2 on OS X 10.8?

I don't care about keeping the Xcode version of "GCC", I just need GCC 4.7.2

Comment: Download gcc 4.7.2. Build it according the instructions. Install it according to the instructions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**MacPorts**

The easiest way is to use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) which provides

> gcc47 @4.7.2 (lang)
>      The GNU compiler collection

Install MacPorts and then

```
sudo port install gcc47
```

This will install several binaries with the `-mp-4.7` (as `gcc-mp-4.7`). You can then activate gcc 4.7 as default with

```
sudo port select gcc mp-gcc47
hash gcc
```

To go back to the Apple LLVM compiler

```
sudo port select gcc none
hash gcc
```

**Manual installation**

Otherwise you can download the tarball from [gnu.org](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) and follow the instructions in the `INSTALL` file (usually `./configure; make; make install`) but you will have to install all the dependencies by yourself.

A manual installation will (if not specified differently with `configure`) install the binaries in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Okay, I've done that, Homebrew is still saying that I'm using the Apple compiler, how can I  change that within Homebrew, or just even regular Terminal?

Comment: Ok by **that** you mean MacPorts or the manual installation?

Comment: @MarcusJ I updated the answer with some post-installation instructions

Comment: I used the Macports method, thanks for the added instruction, I'll try it out in a few hours when I get home.

Comment: Thanks for that command to select the proper GCC version, it appears that that is only MacPorts wide though?

Answer (score 2):

Download a signed Installer package here: https://www.litebeam.net/macosx/macosx/gcc.html